# Xamarin Forms Material Android Entry Numeric Only

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, material-design

I am using Xamarin Forms Visual Material and I cannot find a way to only show a numeric keyboard. I have tried setting the Keyboard property to Numeric as well as setting the EditText InputType in the renderer but the default keyboard always displays. Any thoughts or help?

Comment: Try to set the [Keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#customize-the-keyboard)

Comment: I have tried setting keyboard to keyboard.numeric and it has no effect.

Comment: are you testing on real device?

Comment: Yes, real device (multiple) and emulator. And ios works just fine.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue, have you tried testing with other manufacturers' devices ?You could share a sample if possiable.

Comment: So it was a mistake by me. I had a base view that all my entries derived from. On that base view I set IsUppercase to true which must cause the numeric keyboard to be ignored on Android.